# Steps to apply Hadamard gate to $n$ qubits

Tags: mathematics, textbook-and-exercises

[image]

Can someone shows me, step by step, how to apply Hadamard and output the result?

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/14066/55 and links therein

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that the Hadamard gate has the matrix representation as $H = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $. When you apply Hadamard gates to all the qubits,

[image]

what you essentially doing is applying the operation $U = H \otimes H \otimes H$ to the state $|\psi_2\rangle$. Now,

$$ H \otimes H = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \otimes  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\ 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  $$

To get $ H \otimes H \otimes H $ you have to do another tensor. Thus, applying Hadamard gates to the state $|\psi_2\rangle$ can be written in term of matrix multiplication as

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}}  \\
 \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}}  \\
 \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}}  \\
 \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}}  \\
 \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}}  \\
 \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}}  \\
 \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}}  \\
 \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}}  \\
 \end{bmatrix}   \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\\ -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} \\ -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}} \end{bmatrix} 
=
 \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation}

Now, the resulting vector above can be written in term of the ket representation as your formula $|\psi_{3a} \rangle$. That is,
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{2} \big( |000\rangle + |011\rangle + |100\rangle - |111\rangle \big)
 \end{equation}

Comment: How do you know there are 3 qubits?

Comment: @pyb There are three qubits in your system because if you look at the basis states, there are 3 qubits within it. To see this more clearly, note that the state $|\psi \rangle = \dfrac{|000\rangle + |111\rangle }{\sqrt{2} } = \dfrac{|0\rangle^{\otimes 3} + |1\rangle^{\otimes 3} }{\sqrt{2} }  $ is another three qubit systems. But $|\psi \rangle = \dfrac{|0000\rangle + |1111\rangle }{\sqrt{2} } = \dfrac{|0\rangle^{\otimes 4} + |1\rangle^{\otimes 4} }{\sqrt{2} } $ is a four qubit system.  Now, another 4 qubits state could be: $|\psi \rangle = |0101\rangle $.

Comment: thank you! Do you know of a resource that explains how to go from the $|\psi_3a\rangle$ to the Dirac notation? I know how to convert from the Dirac notation to vectors then apply linear algebra, but not the other way around.

Comment: from the vector notation of |3⟩ to the Dirac notation*

Comment: You can just look at the position of the element in the vector and convert it to binary. For instance, there is a $1$ in the first (0th) position of the vector, so this corresponds to $|000\rangle$. Then there is also a $1$ in the 3rd position of the vector. Now $3$ is binary is $011$ so this corresponds to $|011\rangle$. There is a $1$ in the 4th position, and $4$ in binary is $100$ so this corresponds to $|100\rangle$. Then there is a $1$ in the last spot, the $7th$ position, and $7$ in binary is $111$ thus the state is $|111\rangle$. put them together you have the last line :)

Comment: wow, thank you so much! It will make reviewing intro courses much easier. I miss why the 1st $1$ is encoded to |000⟩ and not |001⟩, but I will figure it out.

Comment: This is because we start counting from $0$. $0$ corresponds to $000$. Then $1$ corresponds to $001$.