# Apply Hadamard on a qubit in a register

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, hadamard

I want to implement a Hadamard gate on a single qubit in a register.
Given two qubits
q0 := $|0\rangle$ and
q1 := $|+\rangle$
I would like to use a Hadamard gate on the first qubit (q0).

My intuition is that

- using Hadamard on the first qubit and building the register afterwards:
  Apply: q0' = Had(q0) = \begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}
  Build Register: reg0 := q0' tensor q1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 \\ 1/2 \\ 1/2 \\ 1/2 \end{bmatrix}
  would lead to the same result as
- using Hadamard Gate (**H**) on the first qubit after building the register:
  Building the register: reg1 := q0 tensor q1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 0 \\ 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
  Apply: **H** tensor **I** mul reg1 =
  \begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} && 0 && 1/\sqrt{2} && 0 \\
              0 && 1/\sqrt{2} && 0 && 1/\sqrt{2} \\
              1/\sqrt{2} && 0 && -1/\sqrt{2} && 0 \\
              0 && 1/\sqrt{2} && 0 && -1/\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}
  mul
  reg1
  = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
  So this is not the same.
  But what would be same is when we swap **H** and **I**:
  **I** tensor **H** mul reg1 =
  \begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} && 1/\sqrt{2} && 0 && 0 \\
  1/\sqrt{2} && -1/\sqrt{2} && 0 && 0 \\
  0 && 0 && 1/\sqrt{2} && 1/\sqrt{2} \\
  0 && 0 && 1/\sqrt{2} && -1/\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}
  mul
  reg1
  =
  \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 \\ 1/2 \\ 1/2 \\ 1/2 \end{bmatrix}

I found a [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/concepts-circuits) and I think it has something to with that. It says:

[image: Microsoft Article]

I think this is weird. Can someone explain it?

Comment: "I think *it* is weird."  Unclear what "it" refers to, and which part you're finding weird.

Comment: Also useful would be this answer: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14066/how-do-i-apply-the-hadamard-gate-to-one-qubit-in-a-two-qubit-pure-state

Comment: The equation after "Building the register: reg1 := q0 tensor q1 =" is not correct. As Frank Yellin says in his answer below, the vector you wrote is $|+\rangle \otimes |0\rangle$, whereas you are looking for $|0\rangle \otimes |+\rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then if you follow your logic after that, you will get the same result as your first method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you find confusing.  You start off with with the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt2 \\ 0 \\ 1/\sqrt2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
which is $|+\rangle \otimes |0\rangle$.

Then:
$$(H\otimes I)(|+\rangle \otimes |0\rangle) = 
(H|+\rangle) \otimes (I|0\rangle) = |0\rangle|0\rangle$$

$$(I\otimes H)(|+\rangle \otimes |0\rangle) = 
(I|+\rangle) \otimes (H|0\rangle) = |+\rangle|+\rangle$$

Which is exactly what you got in your calculations.